# How do I get the storage value of a bigmap using pair datatype as key with taquito library?

Tags: smart-contracts, bigmap, dapps, taquito

I am using the [taquito library](https://tezostaquito.io/) to interact with a smart contract that I have uploaded to carthagenet.

However, I am facing an issue in retrieving the value of a bigmap property in my smart contract storage with pair datatype as the key.

*I have tried the following method and it doesn't work.*

```
// agreements is a property in my storage with bigmap datatype

const bigMapValue = await storage.agreements.get({0:userAddr, 1: senderAddr});
```

*The error that was thrown*

```
Unable to encode big map key: TypeError: this.bigMap.KeySchema.ToBigMapKey is not a function
```

Comment: Thanks for using Taquito. Using a pair as a key is not yet supported in Taquito. We created this issue https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/251 to track. Can you reach out to me as I'd like to get some more details about your use-case.

Comment: Hi Jev, thanks for the answer. May I know how can I reach out to you to share with you more about the dapp that I am building?

Comment: @JevBjörsell can you please move your comment to the answer?

Comment: @Zack You can reach me on my jevonearth telegram handle. We have an update to support this use case, should be released this week. I will add a proper answer at that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Taquito release [v6.1.0-beta.0](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/releases/tag/6.1.0-beta.0) Taquito offers a new API for Maps which support pairs as keys in Maps and BigMaps.

Here's a link to documentation & examples on [Accessing Map values using Pairs](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/maps_bigmaps#accessing-map-values-using-pairs)